# Is it possible to send an audio file along with apns push message

Tags: php, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

This question may look strange, But excuse me.

Is it possible to send an **audio file with push message** ?. So that whenever a push message is received to a device, automatically the audio file is played !

I Know that payload accepts only string, but just want to know other possibilities !
[Resource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1)

So far we tried this way,

A push message is sent to a device. whenever the user selects the push message an alarm is played on the device(Local audio file in iPhone or Ipad).

Answer (score 1):

You can only send a filename of a sound file that is packaged with your application. That file will be played automatically when the notification arrives.  Actually sending a sound file in the payload in not possible.  Even if you encode the data somehow in a way that can be included in the json payload of the notification,  you are limited to 256 bytes, and there isn't much you can send with that.

APN Guide :

> sound
>
> The name of a sound file in the application bundle. The sound in this
>   file is played as an alert. If the sound file doesn’t exist or default
>   is specified as the value, the default alert sound is played. The
>   audio must be in one of the audio data formats that are compatible
>   with system sounds; see “Preparing Custom Alert Sounds” for details.

Comment: So the file name must reside in the device ?

Comment: @Ramarajudantuluri Yes, the sound file should be inside the application bundle. I added the relevant quote from the APNS programming guide.